# How to make a point free array search by value with Ramda

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js, pointfree

```
const documents = [
    {
        mode: 'a',
    },
    {
        mode: 'b',
    }
]

const getMode = R.propEq('mode')
const findInDocuments = (filter) => R.find(filter, documents)          // <-- 1
const findByModeInDocuments = (mode) => findInDocuments(getMode(mode)) // <-- 2
findByModeInDocuments('b')
```

What is the best way to make functions 1 and 2 point free?

Comment: `findInDocuments = R.flip(R.find)(documents)` and `findByModeInDocuments = R.compose(findInDocuments, getMode)` should do

Comment: Ahh this is an amazing and pretty simple answer ^^!

Answer (score 1):

As you say, you can solve it by passing in the key to `propEq`:

```
R.find(R.propEq('mode', 'a'), documents)
```

Another option is to use the `eqProps` function, which tests if two objects match for the named key:

```
R.find(R.eqProps('mode', a), documents)
```

```js
const documents = [
    {
        mode: 'a',
    },
    {
        mode: 'b',
    }
]

console.log(R.find(R.propEq('mode', 'a'), documents))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.24.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you really need to ask *why* you want this point-free.  If it's just a learning exercise, then hitmand has a fairly standard -- and perfectly fine -- Ramda answer.  But I would suggest that in general point-free is only useful so long as it improves readability.  This is more readable to me:

```js
const findByMode = curry ((xs, mode) => find (propEq ('mode', mode), xs))

const documents = [{mode: 'a'}, {mode: 'b'}]

console .log (
  findByMode (documents) ('b')
)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
<script>const {curry, find, propEq} = R                              </script>
```

And if you want `findByModeInDocuments` (better named `findDocumentsByMode`?) just partially apply `documents` to that function.

This, of course it not point-free, but I find it easier to read than the `useWith` solution.  Even easier is the solution from codeepic, although that involves a change in signature from `findByMode (documents) ('b')` to `findByMode ('b') (documents)`, which might or might not be acceptable to you.

Answer (score 0):

this should do the job:

```js
const documents = [{ mode: 'a' }, { mode: 'b' }];

// if `mode` is not unique, then you might consider R.filter instead of R.find
const findByMode = R.useWith(R.find, [
  R.propEq('mode'),
  R.identity
]);

// you can use partial application to apply the documents list
const findDocumentsByMode = findByMode(R.__, documents);
// or
// const findDocumentsByMode = R.partialRight(findByMode, [documents]);


console.log('findByMode', findDocumentsByMode('a'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js" integrity="sha256-xB25ljGZ7K2VXnq087unEnoVhvTosWWtqXB4tAtZmHU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try something like that - it is quite similar to your `findByModeInDocuments` function signature but you pass `documents` param in, so it's more flexible but also more self explanatory for anyone reading the code.
Since now you can use the function with any list, it should be named more generic: `findByMode`.

```js
const documents = [
  {
    mode: 'a',
  },
  {
    mode: 'b',
  }
];

const findByMode = v => R.find(R.propEq('mode', v))


console.log('findByMode', findByMode ('b')(documents));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js" integrity="sha256-xB25ljGZ7K2VXnq087unEnoVhvTosWWtqXB4tAtZmHU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```